# Angularjs controlling ng-show of sibling element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am working on a ranking system where user can rank images from select box but I want to restrict user not to select same rank for multiple images. I got this working with below approach.

I have error message div set ng-show="showError" is set to false on page load when the user select rank 1 for first image and second image then second image show the error message. Then if the use change the rank of second image to something else then error message goes away. Works well!

The problem occurs when the user change the rank of of first image where there is no error message then I can't clear the error message from second image.

It becomes more complicated when I have to clear the message from multiple images which were assign same ranks.

HTML

```
<div class="thumHolder">
<div ng-repeat="img in data" class="thumbnails" id="thumbnails{{$index+1}}">
    <div class="thumbImg" open-modal>
        <img ng-src="images/thumb/{{img.name}}.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="thumbInfo">
        <select name="imgRank{{$index+1}}" class="imgRank" id="imgRank{{$index+1}}" ng-model="imgRk" select-on-change>
            <option ng-repeat="r in rankArr" value="{{r}}">{{r}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="errMsg" ng-show="showError">{{errorMags}}</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
.directive('selectOnChange', [
function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
            scope.$watch('imgRk', function(rnk, oldRnk) {
                if (scope.userRank.indexOf(rnk) !== -1 && rnk !== '0') {
                    scope.showError = true;
                    scope.errorMags = "Rank " + rnk + " is already selected"
                } else {
                    scope.showError = false;
                }
                scope.userRank[scope.$index] = rnk;

            });
        }
    };
}])
```

Thanks

Comment: Suggest you create a demo that replicates problem. Also seems like using an event handler would be more practical like `ng-change`

Comment: Yeah, I used ng-change before but then there was lot of dom manipulation so switch to directory. I wll try to create demo. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by a lot of dom manipulation. Should be simple to pass the whole object to controller and store as `selectedObject` and keep track when a change is made